# How to restrict a column value to be same as other columns? [Postgresql]

Tags: postgresql

Below is the `match` table, which keeps record of all the matches between players from players table.
You can see that the `winner_player` should be either `player_1` or `player_2`, I mean it should give error if I do insert any other player_id except `player_1` or `player_2`. But now I can insert any player_id (number) in this column.

| match_id | player_1 | player_2 | winner_player |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 | 6 | 5 |
| 4 | 15 | 16 | 16 |

**My question:** how can I restrict `winner_player` column to be same as either `player_1` or `player_2`

Comment: `check` PS Re (re)search: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & sometimes limited to titles, but read the help. Google re googling/searching, including in Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: What have you research about your problem so far? Have you looked at the documentation regarding *check constraints*? (that's a clue btw)

Comment: The answer is yes it's certainly possible `check (winner_player in (player_1, player_2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other peoples help I am posting the @Stu's answer here:

`CHECK (winner_player in (player_1, player_2))`

learn more about `check` constraint here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS